# img without src prints alt text

Tags: image, background, src, alt

i have dynamically generated images

```
<img class="item" src=""  style="background-image: url( {{ imgBG.image.path }} ); background-position: bottom center; background-size: cover;" alt="{{ imgBG.home_img_alt }}" />
```

but without a src to a file I see alt text. I cannot use src, need to work with background-image
Anything can be done here?
thanks

Comment: So, why do you use an `image` at all?

Comment: for indexing (alt attr)

Comment: is this a bug or? why it shows alt text if no src given?

Comment: @aleXela it's not a bug, if you have set the `alt` attribute, and the image cannot be found, it will print the text instead. If you want to avoid the text to be visible, remove the `alt`  attribute.

Comment: can I use `<div role="img" aria-label="adorable puppy playing on the grass"></div>` instead of img + alt? 
I need to give for an image its alt text. but as far as I found alt only works with img tags.